# Python: Creating fast api request with valid custom headers

Tags: python, http, testing, request, fastapi

Was struggling in finding how to create a fast.Request object with custom headers for testing.
Spent around 3 hours searching for it. Adding it here so that you can save some time.

Answer (score 0):

```
#create any header/s that you want, then create dictionary of headers.
jwt_token = create_jwt_token("tenant_123")
valid_headers = {
        "Authorization": "Bearer "+jwt_token
}

#using Headers class from starlette.datastructures is the key
from starlette.datastructures import Headers
req = fastapi.Request(
        {
            "type": "http",
            "headers": Headers(valid_headers).raw,
        })
```